# How to make Qt Creator use Rosetta and x86 compiler on Mac M1?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, apple-m1, rosetta

I am using **Qt 5.15.2** on my **Mac mini** with **M1** chip. This works fine (due to Rosetta). Below is the list of compilers Qt Creator found on this computer, and among them is the  **C++, x86 64bit** that I use. No problem.

[image: compilers amiable on the first M1 computer]

I would like to use the same settings on a (somewhat newer)  **Mac Book Pro** (also with **M1** chip).  Below is the list of compilers Qt Creator finds on this computer, the *x86 is now missing!*

[image: compilers amiable on the new M1 computer]

I do not know if I have a x86 compiler on the new M1-computer. I have installed Xcode and the command line tools for XCode 13.2.

1. Can I somewhere tell Qt Creator that the deployment target is x86?
2. Does /usr/bin/clang++ only compile for the ARM/M1-chip, or can it also produce and link to x86 code?
3. if not, how can I find out if there is an x86 compiler on my new M1-computer?
4. If the compiler is missing, how to install it?

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: May help: https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-on-apple-silicon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few tips that can help, I just setup a project using Qt 5.15.2 on a 2021 M1 Mac.

*Note this will likely be different for Qt >= 6.*

> 1. Can I somewhere tell Qt Creator that the deployment target is x86?

Yes, you can do this using specific argument in the build settings of your kit.

- Add the `QMAKE_APPLE_DEVICE_ARCHS="x86_64"` additional argument to qmake.
- Also, add an additional CMake option: `-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING="x86_64"`

ℹ️ Click `Manage Kits`.. in the projects view to open the preferences editor where you can update your CMake configuration.

---

> 2. Does /usr/bin/clang++ only compile for the ARM/M1-chip, or can it also produce and link to x86 code?

With rosetta installed (`/usr/sbin/softwareupdate –install-rosetta –agree-to-license`), and the configuration above, yes you can compile and link x86 binaries.